# Error in updating an array when a table view with two buttons is selected

Tags: ios, swift

I have a tableview with two buttons and a label and I want to save the text in the label in two different arrays based on the button I select.

| _Add Button_______Label______________Favourites Button___|
| _Add Button_______Label______________Favourites Button___|

When I select the add button I want the label to be saved in Add Button Array and when I select the Favorites Button I want to save the text in favorites.

The code I did below works fine for the Add Button but always stores the first cell for the favorite button. What am I missing here?

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! SegmentControlCell
        cell.addPointsLabel.text? = SegmentNetworkCallObj.AFResponse[indexPath.row]["Description"] as? String ?? ""
        cell.addTaskButton.tag = indexPath.row
        cell.addTaskButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(addButtontapped(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
        cell.addTaskButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(favouriteButtonTapped(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
            return cell
        }

//Button Selection
@IBAction func addButtontapped(_ sender: Any) {
        let selectedTask = SegmentNetworkCallObj.AFResponse[(sender as AnyObject).tag]["Description"]
        dailyDeedsArray.append(selectedTask as! String)
        print("addbutton",dailyDeedsArray)
}

    @IBAction func favouriteButtonTapped(_ sender: Any) {
        let selectedTask = SegmentNetworkCallObj.AFResponse[(sender as AnyObject).tag]["Description"]
        favouritesArray.append(selectedTask as! String)
        print("favourites",favouritesArray)

    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you have 2 buttons in each cell, one called `addTaskButton` and another presumably called `addFavoriteButton` or something similar, but you only assign & update the tag value for `addTaskButton` in the `tableView` delegate method, which is a problem for your favorites button because you access `(sender as AnyObject).tag` in both `IBAction` methods. Also, you assign 2 different targets for `addTaskButton`, which I guess is a mistake.

I think the code should look something like this:

```
cell.addTaskButton.tag = indexPath.row
cell.addTaskButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(addButtontapped(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)

cell.addFavoriteButton.tag = indexPath.row
cell.addFavoriteButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(favouriteButtonTapped(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
```